# Getting wrong results from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get total purchased products, total sold product and total sold price with following query

```
SELECT products.name, products.code, 
COALESCE( sum( purchase_items.quantity ) , 0 ) AS purchased, 
COALESCE( sum( sale_items.quantity ) , 0 ) AS sold,
COALESCE(sum(sale_items.gross_total), 0) as sold_price
FROM ( `products` )
LEFT JOIN `purchase_items` ON `purchase_items`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `sale_items` ON `sale_items`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `sales` ON `sale_items`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `purchases` ON `purchase_items`.`purchase_id` = `purchases`.`id`
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
ORDER BY `purchased` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

[SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44e19/4).

Table data:

```
NAME            CODE    PURCHASED   SOLD    SOLD_PRICE
test product 3  test3   4           4       1600
test product 2  test2   4           4       2000
test product 1  test1   4           4       1200
```

I am getting this:

```
test product 1  test1   4   4   1200
test product 3  test3   4   4   1600
test product 2  test2   4   4   2000
```

This is the correct results:

```
test product 1  test1   2   2   400
test product 3  test3   2   2   1200
test product 2  test2   2   2   800
```

Comment: What subquery? All I see is some joins. Please show us what you get and what you expect.

Comment: You want to get `sum(sale_items.gross_total)` - for product 1 : 400. But the table `sale_items` from SQLFiddle contains for product 1: 2 records, one with gross_total = 200, and another with 400. Could you explain why the sum of 200+400 = 400 ? Maybe I'am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I got an other right result?

And to make it clear sqlfiddle shows the result :)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44e19/38

```
test product 1  test1   2   2   600
test product 3  test3   2   2   1000
test product 2  test2   2   2   800
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your posted costs/prices/counts dont appear to match that from your sql fiddle create (probably copy/paste), I'm trying to understand WHAT you want.  Having dealt with inventory systems (and customized in the past), you are trying to find out either most popular product, and/or most profitable based on costs vs actual sales.

To resolve this, you need to look at your cost of goods sold (summation of all your actual purchase items) that it COST YOU to do business.  Then similarly, what IS being sold.  You could have 100's of products and some of them never move, others go through inventory a lot.  These ACTUAL SALES is the other half.  Although this query does not deal with LIFO/FIFO accounting method for inventory and allocation of lot costs, it is probably closer to what you are looking for.

The query starts with the products table and then has a left-join to a summation of just purchases, and a left-join to a summation of actual sales.  I've grabbed the respective totals from each set to do with as you need.

Additionally, I've computed the GROSS PROFIT as the final cost-basis of an individual product (again, not LIFO or FIFO method) and said From the Total Actual Sales, subtract out however many quantity TIMES that of the last known cost as held in the products table.  This gives the gross profit based on only those actually sold.

[SQL Fiddle Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44e19/40)

```
SELECT
      p.id,
      p.code,
      p.name,
      COALESCE( PCosts.totalQty, 0 ) as PurchasedQty,
      COALESCE( PCosts.totalDollar, 0 ) as PurchasedCosts,
      COALESCE( PSales.totalQty, 0 ) as SoldQty,
      COALESCE( PSales.totalDollar, 0 ) as TotalSales,
      COALESCE( PSales.totalDollar, 0 ) - ( COALESCE( PSales.totalQty, 0 ) * p.Cost ) as GrossProfit
   from
      products p
         left join ( SELECT
                           pi.product_id,
                           SUM( pi.quantity ) totalQty,
                           SUM( pi.gross_total ) totalDollar
                        from
                           purchase_items pi
                        group by
                           pi.product_id ) PCosts
            ON p.id = PCosts.product_ID
         left join ( SELECT
                           si.product_id,
                           SUM( si.quantity ) as totalQty,
                           SUM( si.gross_total ) as totalDollar
                        from
                           sale_items si
                        group by 
                           si.product_id ) PSales
            ON p.id = PSales.product_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you time. I have realized my mistake the gross_total for sqlfiddle schema was wrong. Can you please suggest me any book on these calculation methods LIFO and FIFO. Thanks again

Comment: @Saleem, LIFO / FIFO should be in basic accounting books.  However, typically there is some indicator tracked on which "lot" from purchase the counts come from and that gets into very detailed inventory tracking and nothing close to what you currently have.  Sorry I can not offer more on this forum for that amount of context.  If you ARE interested in more, and some of my history in accounting in this area, shoot me an email.